# Initialize List with null datatypes in C#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm using C# to build an application, i have a model with these properties

```
     public class FormNXPModel{
        [Key]
        public int Id {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string AppNumber {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string FormNumber {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string ExporterName{get; set; }
     }
```

but when i run my api and try to populate a list

```
  public IActionResult GetFormNXPs(){
    var forms = new List<FormNXPModel>();
    forms = db.FormNXPs.ToList();
    return Ok(forms);
  }
```

My output comes out camel-cased, not as the model...

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "appNumber": "XG0191019",
    "formNumber": "formXg00111",
    "exporterName": "Zambai Ltd",
 }
```

my observation

```
"AppNumber"  becomes "appNumber",
"FormNumber" becomes "formNumber",
"ExporterName" becomes "exporterName"
```

....and so on, please how to i resolve this.

Comment: How are you getting your "output"? You should post a minimally-viable sample of code that you currently have, and what your expected output is.

Comment: In cast you're developing an MVC app, are you using any JSON contract resolvers in your ConfigureServices method?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format) you can see Google JSON Style guide. But if u want to change use newtonsoft.json `[JsonProperty("AppNumber")]`

```
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("AppNumber")]
    public string AppNumber {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("FormNumber")]
    public string FormNumber {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("ExporterName")]
    public string ExporterName {get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you're working on a .NET Core 3.x project:**

You can disable the default naming policy by changing the PropertyNamingPolicy to `null`. This will leave all property names untouched by default when serializing to JSON.

```
// Startup.cs / ConfigureServices
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null
        });
}
```